# Android How to open up a browser window from an activity with URL?

Tags: android

How do I open up browser window within my activity.  Ideally I would like them to stay inside my app with some type of embedded webkit activity view?  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you can use **Web View** 
[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) you can find a tutorial on doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-embed-a-webview-with-the-webkit-engine/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm if you just want to present the link inside a TextView, you can use a span to make the links clickable (it will be handled with the browser, clicking back will go back to the activity that contains the link):

```
  URLSpan span = new URLSpan(url);
  textView.getText().setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

If you're rendering content with links, you might want to look into the [Linkfy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class.